# how to get specific line in a string array foreach

Tags: c#

Hello i am tring to get a specific line from a string array with using [] but i am getting only 2 characters? Can you please explain this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] longtext = { "Káva je nápoj z upražených a rozemletých semen plodů kávovníku. Označují se tak i samotná semena", 
                          "případně semena rozemletá na prášek. Káva je charakteristická svou silnou vůní (aroma) a černou barvou. Obsahuje mimo jiné alkaloid kofein, který povzbuzuje srdeční činnost a zvyšuje krevní tlak. Především se káva pije pro své povzbuzující účinky. Je také velmi oblíbeným nápojem při setkávání lidí a je často podávána po jídle (jako jakási „tečka“ či pro lepší trávení). K největším producentům patří Brazílie",
                          " Vietnam, Kolumbie a Indonésie. Nejčastěji se pije káva ze zrnek druhu arabika a robusta. Káva je druhou nejprodávanější komoditou na světě (po ropě).[1]" };

    foreach(var line in longtext)                        
        Console.WriteLine(line[2]);
}
```

Comment: `longtext[2]` is likely what you meant to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let's look what you have

```
string[] longtext { ... , ... , ... }
```

You have created an array of string.

To get the second element of `longtext` (which is an *array*), you just need to call the array indexer i.e `longtext[1]`

```
Console.WriteLine(longtext[1]);
```

**Output**

```
případně semena rozemletá na prášek. Káva je charakteristická svou silnou vůní (aroma) a černou barvou. Obsahuje mimo jiné alkaloid kofein, který povzbuzuje srdeční činno
```

---

**Further reading**

- [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)
- [Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays)
- [Accessing Individual Characters of a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#accessing-individual-characters)

Answer (score 2):

You just call the line to print. When you use the [] brackets, you tell the programm to print a character of the line. In your case at the index of 2.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string[] longtext = { "Káva je nápoj z upražených a rozemletých semen plodů kávovníku. Označují se tak i samotná semena", 
                "případně semena rozemletá na prášek. Káva je charakteristická svou silnou vůní (aroma) a černou barvou. Obsahuje mimo jiné alkaloid kofein, který povzbuzuje srdeční činnost a zvyšuje krevní tlak. Především se káva pije pro své povzbuzující účinky. Je také velmi oblíbeným nápojem při setkávání lidí a je často podávána po jídle (jako jakási „tečka“ či pro lepší trávení). K největším producentům patří Brazílie",
                " Vietnam, Kolumbie a Indonésie. Nejčastěji se pije káva ze zrnek druhu arabika a robusta. Káva je druhou nejprodávanější komoditou na světě (po ropě).[1]" };

            foreach(var line in longtext)

                Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var line in longtext)
    Console.WriteLine(line[2]);
```

This does print the second character of each line.

```
var lines = Regex.Split(longtext, "\r\n|\r|\n");
```

This can split the long text into lines, so you can easily access the line you need.

```
Console.WriteLine(line[1]);
```